# $n \choose k$ with at least one element, and conditional probability on it

Tags: combinatorics, conditional-probability

**The Example:**
There are 5 people in a room.
The chance of each one of them to get outside is $p$.
Then, the chance of a person outside being struck by a lightning is 0.05. 
What is the chance that at least one person will be struck by lightning?

I was thinking about:
$$
{5 \choose 1}p(1-p)^4*0.05 + {5 \choose 2}p^2(1-p)^3*(1-0.95^2) + ...+{5 \choose 5}p^5*(1-0.95^5)
$$

Though it seems too long.
 **Is there a more efficient way to calculate this?**

Comment: Yes, there is a more efficient way. Find the probability that no one is struck by lightening, the subtract from one.

Comment: So the chance of each one of them to get struck by a lightning is $0.05p$.

Comment: @peterwhy thanks for the fast answer! I wasn't sure if this was valid - though it seems easy when you put it that way. Thanks a lot!